# Cross Debug Win32 Mingw32 C/C++ program on Linux and Wine using GDB

Tags: gcc, gdb, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I installed mingw-w64 and gdb-mingw-w64 on Ubuntu 14.10 using:

`sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
sudo apt-get install gdb-mingw-w64`

I'm able to compile C/C++ programs and run them from Wine or on Windows machine.

I installed mingw32 version of gdb to be able to debug windows app compiled with Mingw.

I tried to use recent versions of Netbeans 8, Code::Blocks 13.12, Eclipse Luna and was able to configure Mingw toolchain to be used with IDE for building win32 application from Linux.

I also tried to configure the same way in those IDEs to use Mingw version of GDB (gdb-mingw-w64) the same way as standrad GDB was sued for non-mingw GCC toolchain but was never able to make it work :(

How can I debug such C/C++ program compiled with Mingw from Linux? 
How to configure in any of IDEs listed above?

Thank you!

Comment: First get gdb debugging working in a command line console (if you haven't already). Once you have that working you can figure out how to integrate it into an IDE.